# Determining the minSDKVersion for an Android app

Tags: android, flutter, targetsdkversion

The question is asking for guidance on determining the minimum required SDK (software development kit) version that should be set for an Android app

I am looking for guidance on how to choose the appropriate minimum required SDK version to set for my Android app. How to assess the compatibility and functionality tradeoffs associated with different SDK versions

Comment: The minSDK is determined by the features you want to use. Some features are not available on older Android versions and thus if you want or have to use a feature you have to set the minSDK accordingly or you have to provide an alternative implementation for older devices. But there are too many features to give you a general advice which minSDK to use without knowing in detail what app you want to develop and what features you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

The packages that you add to your project who determines what is the `minSDK`
but mostly `21` is the sweet spot , most of packages needs no more than **21** . like Google Maps , AdMob etc .....

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on the APIs your code and packages you use require. For most projects 21 is fine, but some packages require to set it higher, it is usually mentioned in the Readme file or homepage of the package on pub.dev.